# Is there a Matlab function or codes to calculate SNRdB of 5D signal?

Tags: matlab, signals

I am doing a 5D data reconstruction from 5D noisy data. I am looking for any MATLAB codes or functions to calculate the SNR (in dB) in order to compare the noisy data with the original 5D data. Is there any way to do this using MATLAB?

Answer (score 1):

Use: `r = snr(x,y)`

[From Matlab documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/snr.html): **`r = snr(x,y)`** returns the signal-to-noise ratio (SNR) in **decibels** of a signal, x, by computing the ratio of its summed squared magnitude to that of the noise, y. y must have the same dimensions as x. Use this form when the input signal is not necessarily sinusoidal and you have an estimate of the noise.